# How to display the activity into full screen and vice versa on tapping the activity?

Tags: android, android-webview, fullscreen, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

In my application, i am using Tabhost and I have placed the webview inside tab host to show the contents.When the user taps the screen the contents should be displayed in fullscreen and vice versa but this is not happening.How to acheive this?Please Suggest me some ideas !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
```

this code on your eventlistener.